# How to display "+" in front-end Wordpress + Handlebars?

Tags: wordpress, handlebars.js

I have a Wordpress website and LazyBlocks plugin which using Handlebars.js to output data. There is a problem - I can't display the "+" in front-end because it cuts the "+". Interesting that it happen only when I use field "Repeater" then fields inside don't display the "+". Anybody use this plugin ever? May be you had the same problem...

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: This might be related to [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73463149/php-file-is-replacing-first-single-quote-with) where ">" was being replaced with &#8216;